# When is it ok to combine 2 viewmodels into 1 instead of using some form of viewmodel-viewmodel communication?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, eventaggregator

I have 2 viewmodels that each have their own view.

the first view model has 3 properties being displayed by the view:

```
PolicyProvider

PolicyType

PolicyNumber
```

the second view model has only 1 property being displayed by its view:

```
TypeOfInvestmentFund
```

There is a 1 to many relationship between the `PolicyType` and the `TypeOfInvestmentFund.`

Both of these view models and their views are being displayed as user controls inside a parent form.

**The available choices for the `TypeOfInvestmentFund` is dependent on which `PolicyType` is selected in the other view**.

---

To me this feels like these 2 view models could be combined, because

**a)** they are clearly somewhat coupled

**b)** the controls are both so small and simple that joining them will not create a complex and unmanageable object.

However this data is fairly unrelated; unrelated enough that the user would still want the data visible in seperate parts of the form (and therefore be placed on seperate views).

I personally feel that combining these 2 view models and having 2 seperate views connect to it to display different parts of it is a lot less overhead then managing the communication between the 2 objects.

I could however create loosely coupled events with the Prism Event Aggregator, and although I have never done this it is probably not much to manage, and keeping these 2 view models seperate would preserve seperation of concerns. Furthermore if other controls were to appear later on in development that also need this information, I cant keep absorbing them, so starting an event aggregator at this stage would prevent rework as the events would be available already to subscribe to. It is still more work then just combining the view models.

Which one of these 2 is 'more correct'? I understand its a judgement call, but I can't decide so I'm looking for opinions to help me make up my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thank you for the replies. Got a bunch of ideas from Rachels suggestion (upvote for you ma'am) but none of them paned out. In the end the project manager didn't like the idea and wants me to implement a more standard approach for readability and to prevent rework, so I'm going to go the message root.

Instead of eventaggregator I'm just going to make the parent subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of the `Policy` child and then change a property of the `TypeOfInvestment` child.

I'm kinda bummed I didnt get to implement the viewmodel merge as it really made more sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

A ViewModel reflects the View, not the Data

If your View shows a `Policy` and a dynamic `TypeOfInvestmentFund`, then by all means your ViewModel should have both those objects.

Personally I would have my ViewModel expose a `Policy` model to the View, and have the `PolicyModel` contain properties for `Provider`, `Type`, `Number`, and `InvestmentFund`

I could then use DataTemplates to tell WPF how to draw each object. Here's a rough example outlining how you would do that:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PolicyModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:PolicyView />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding InvestmentFund}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:InvestmentFundA}">
    <local:InvestmentFundA />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:InvestmentFundB}">
    <local:InvestmentFundB />
</DataTemplate>
```

**Edit**

If `Policy` and `TypeOfInvestment` are two separate objects, I'd keep their `Models` separate, and put them both in the same `ViewModel`. `Models` are for modeling your data, while `ViewModels` are for modeling your `View`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your suggestion is to combine the models instead of the viewmodels. This probably wouldnt work for me. Your answer makes complete sence in the context of the question, but I think I oversimplified the example. The data in question is not really the data the views and viewmodels are working with, but it is actually the data **about the view**. We are creating an autosave for the system and I am essentially saving the state of the view to be loaded later. And because each view can opperate independantly (asside from this one time) I want to keep the data seperate

Comment: @ExitMusic The first bit should still apply: If your view contains two different models, then have both items in the ViewModel. Usually I have one View per Page, not one View per Model

Comment: The thing is that there is a view with a `Policy` and another **seperate** view with a `TypeOfInvestmentFund`. Both Views are intended to be able to be used independently. There is a parent view with these views nested in it as usercontrols. I would normally put them both in one view, but I want them to be reusable seperately (sometimes you might want to change the `Policy`, but have no use of the `TypeOfInvestmentFund`) so they will be in different views. I hope that makes sense ^_^

Comment: @ExitMusic lol I'm really confused now. Your question seems to be asking if you should combine the two ViewModels, but in your comments you are saying you want to keep them separate... I'm afraid I don't understand. I don't know what to tell you other than that your ViewModel is the model for your View, not a model for your Models. Put whatever is displayed in the View inside of it, and keep in mind that you don't have to map everything 1:1. Quite often I'll create a DataTemplate or View for a Model, and use it inside multiple other Views which reflect different ViewModels

Comment: I want to keep the views separate, but I am suggesting that the 2 views' datacontexts are the same view model. I'm talking about combining **view models** and keeping the **views** separate. I assumed when you say "The first bit should still apply" that you were talking about the "If your View shows a `Policy` and a dynamic `TypeOfInvestmentFund`..." part of your answer. But my View does not show a `Policy` **and** a `TypeOfInvestment`; the `Policy` is shown in one View while the `TypeOfInvestment` is shown in another. My question is about combining the viewmodels for those 2 views together.

Comment: @ExitMusic If `Policy` and `TypeOfInvestment` are two separate objects, I'd keep their `Models` separate, and put them both in the same `ViewModel`.` `Models` are for modeling your data, while `ViewModels` are for modeling your View

Comment: yea exactly that's what I was trying to say : )

Answer (score 1):

I look at problems like this as being very similar to database normalization.  On the one hand, normalization is good practice, as is creating two separate view models.  But at the same time a certain amount of denormalization has been known to help performance as well.

> I personally feel that combining these 2 view models and having 2 seperate views connect to it to display different parts of it is a lot less overhead then managing the communication between the 2 objects.

And that statement says it all.  While combining the two view models might not be considered "best practice", the feeling I'm getting from you is that it makes sense for your application (based-on the levels of coupling and complexity that you mentioned).  I would say go ahead and combine them and keep an eye on how it performs.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately performance isnt the only concideration here. I talked to another person on the project and she said that the problem with this approach is extensibility (like I mentioned in the question we cant keep merging viewmodels if more issues pop up) and readability. So far every view has a viewmodel, and she doesnt want to break that because if someone else looks at the code later they may very well be confused. I think I'm just going to have to put in the event aggregator.